# angularfire $remove not removing

Tags: angularfire

I have this function and all I want to do is run $remove() on it

```
 retrieveSingleQuestion: function (schoolID, questionID) {
        return $firebase(ref.child(schoolID).child('questions').child(questionID)).$asObject();
    }
```

for some reason, it's not being removed. What do you think it could be?

Answer (score 0):

You should only ever construct AngularFire objects if you will bind them to the scope. In other cases, you're better off staying inside the regular Firebase JavaScript SDK.

E.g.

```
removeQuestion: function(schoolID, questionID) {
    ref.child(schoolID).child('questions).child(questionId).remove();
}
```

AngularFire is built on top of the Firebase JavaScript SDK, so they play nice together. Say that you're showing the questions for that school somewhere on the screen with a `$firebaseArray()`, that list will be auto-updated.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. I ended up using regular firebase for this operation. Appreciate the advice.